# Implement a python dictionary in C++ and update the dictionary

Tags: python, c++, dictionary

I have a python dictionary whose keys are 1D arrays (or vectors) and the value of a key is a set or 1D arrays (or a 2D matrix).

I wonder if there is a way to implement or a library in C++ that can build a python-like dictionary data structure. And when I am looping over a set of vectors, I could update my dictionary like

```
dict = {}
for vk in VK:
{
    if vk not in dict.keys():
       dict.update({vk:matrixk})
}
```

Comment: Looking for [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) ? ...Umm... How about some [good C++ resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: You're probably looking for boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html